# How to change folders/files emblems recursively in linux?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, linux-mint

I want to change my folder emblems recursively. I know that the command `gvfs-set-attribute -t string ~/Desktop/ metadata::emblems []` can change the emblem of only Desktop.

How can I change whole folders and the files emblems? I tried `gvfs-set-attribute -t stringv ~/* metadata::emblems []` but it returns error `Error setting attribute: Setting attribute /home/taygun/Desktop not supported`.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description: Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could feed the command into find:

```
find ~/ -type d -exec gvfs-set-attribute -t stringv {} metadata::emblems [] \;
```

There are some known issues with the defaultdir `~` on some distros with `gvfs-set-attribute` (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1368676)

Consider upgrading to the latest version if you're not already on it.

Comment: The gvfs package version is `1.28.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.3` which is the updated one for Ubuntu 16.04. If I run this code, it gives `find: missing argument to -exec`. Can you show how to hold all folders/files paths as a variable? Maybe sending each files/folders path into `gvfs-set-attribute` into "for loop" can solve the problem.

Comment: I forgot to add `\;`. In order to execute recursively, find should work for what you're trying to do.